# Java Regex matching with parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to come up with the regex to find strings matching the following pattern:

(someNumber - someNumber) With the parenthesis included.

I tried:

```
"\\([1-9]*-[1-9]*\\)"
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

I also need to match:

The letter W or L followed by (someNumber - someNumber) With the parenthesis included.

I tried to use the same pattern above, slightly modified, but again, no luck:

```
"W|L \\([1-9]*-[1-9]*\\)"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can we see how you are using your regexes? Some code example with input and expected output would be very helpful to find and explain your mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Include W|L in parentheses:

```
(W|L)
```

If you want to include space characters before and after the minus, add \s or a space before and after -

```
"((W|L)\\s)?\\([1-9]*\\s-\\s[1-9]*\\)"
```

If you already know that there will be at least one digit, use `+` instead of `*`, as `*` matches zero or more, whereas `+` matches 1 or more.

The pattern given above matches with and without a W or L in front.
Here's a pattern that matches with and without space around the `-` and with or without W or L in front. Additionally, it also captures numbers containing `0`, which you excluded in your original regular expression.

```
"((W|L)\\s)?\\(\\d+\\s?-\\s?\\d+\\)"
```

Comment: When I put in "W (10-5)" I'm only getting the W returned as a match. Wonder why?

Comment: See the updated answer and try the last regular expression mentionned. Works for me. How are you retrieving the result? If you are using m.group(1), that returns "W". Use m.group() or m.group(0) to get the whole match.

Comment: I'm iterating over the matches(while m.find()), and adding m.group() to an arraylist of Strings.

Comment: Do you still only get W, even with the regex as given above?

Comment: So it should match 'W (5-10)' right? The 2nd regex string you posted?

Comment: The last one is more flexible concerning whitespace, use that or delete \\s from the other one. If that's not working, I will have to look at your code.

Comment: The W or L part is not in parenthesis, maybe I didn't explain it correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49502/discussion-between-blueygh2-and-user1154644)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
"(W|L)\\s*\\(\\d+-\\d+\\)"

Comment: This matches with any number of `W`s followed by any number of `L`s. We can do better than that!

Answer (score 0):

Further to blueygh2's answer, your regex will fail if the numbers contain zeroes. My guess is you want to avoid leading zeroes, in which case use `[1-9]\d*` (or `[1-9][0-9]*`). If you want to allow the numbers to equal `0` but otherwise avoid leading zeroes, do `([1-9]\d*|0)`.